# DatabasePHP: Created user A accesses Database of created user B and vice versa

Tags: php, mysql

I developed a website in php script and connected it to a database. There I set up various user accounts for customers. Now my problem is that every user I create always accesses the same database. For example, I create user A who has his own functions there, such as creating a customer account or creating a product for his shop. If I create user B he will access the same database or user B would have all the data of user A and vice versa. How can I set it up so that each user I have created has their own database and cannot access another database? The website is online and working as it should, except for this point.

Comment: You can stick to one database and use the same tables for all users. Just add a `user_id` column to each table where you store what user owns specific records. Then when you make queries, you can select so you only get the data owned by that user:  `WHERE user_id = ?`. It's hard to be much more specific since we don't really know any specifics about the applications architecture or or your code.

Comment: There would be no special way or shortcut to do that. You would have to build and adapt your code and software architecture to do that. Separate databases for each users might be an overkill though, but it would depend if you really want to achieve full isolation, then you'd want to consider that, but it'll be more work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't really how databases work.  I won't go into exactly how to do this, because there are many good resources online, but it's best to think of a database as a central store of information that everyone accesses.  Instead of having each person have their own database, we generally associate each person with an identifier, either an ID or username.  We then associate stored information with this identifier.  For example, we might have a timesheets table with the columns:

`id,punch_in,punch_out,employee_id`

Then, when getting the time records for a given employee, you would do something like:

`SELECT punch_in,punch_out FROM timesheets WHERE employee_id = MY_EMPLOYEE_ID`

The above statement says: "Get all punches in and punches out from the timsheets table, as long as they match a certain employee ID."  You can go much deeper than this, but this is an effective way to segment data records and keep everyone's data to themselves.  If all you have is a user name, you can use something called a join, which merges two tables on a shared index.

There are many ways to achieve these goals, but the key takeaway of setting up a database is that each distinct type of thing should have its own table, for example a table for employees and one for timesheets, and if they relate to each other, they should share an index so you can associate them with each other.

You'll find lots of good resources [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to set permissions at a more granular level, in MySQL and most DBMS it is simplest to do at the database level. Note that a single instance of MySQL can (and likely already does) have multiple databases. So your first task is to seperate the functionality out into different databases, then apply appropriate permissions for each user, making sure you don't alreay have permissions set against a wildcard username.